# Silverlight: Stream file to new HTML browser window to prompt user to "open or save as..."?

Tags: c#, silverlight, file, silverlight-4.0

What would be the most efficient way, if it can be done, to stream or send a file (byte array) from a Silverlight in-browser application to a new HTML window in a way that will prompt the user to either open the file with the default OS application associated, or save the file?

I'm using a save file dialog to allow them to save the file if need be, but I have a requirement such that if a user clicks the file in my application, the standard operating system "open/save" dialog should pop.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2511957/opening-response-stream-in-silverlight

Comment: Where to the file bytes actually originate?  Is it a file from the server?

Comment: @anthony, yes it's from the file server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the file is on the server why not let the browser handle it all:-

```
 HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(urlToFile, "_blank");
```

Comment: This is actually the route I'm looking at taking. In our case, our API layer is an MVC web app, so I'll add an action to return the filestream and let the browser handle it.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Served up the file, opened it in a new window with URL to file, set up the MIME type and everything and it works exactly as desired. Thx again.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your requirements are for a desktop app, not a Silverlight app. Ever looked into [ClickOnce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClickOnce)?

The most plausible way I can think of doing this is sending the file to a remote server and then directing your user to that server. Which is probably not what you're looking for.

Then there's the option of opening a socket and effectively turning your Silverlight app into a server. Then open a new browser window and have it point to localhost:portnum. However you would need to implement some protocol that the browser understands, like FTP or HTTP. Which seems a bit ludicrous.